# Will this RAM work for me? (Late 2009 iMac)

Tags: imac, memory, desktop

I have a 27-inch iMac late 2009 desktop computer and i'm looking to upgrade my ram. The best RAM I can find is a [Kingston 2GB, DDR3-1066, PC3-8500, CL7, DIMM](http://www.ascent.co.nz/productspecification.aspx?ItemID=9396761).

What I currently have is 4GB 1067 MHz Ram

Will this be suitable? Or is this the wrong one?

Answer (score 3):

You can find out the memory summary by going to:

 > About This Mac > More Info > Memory

[image]

<sup>Screenshot example</sup>

You can also go to [Technical Specifications](http://support.apple.com/specs/), click "Browse by Product", and enter the serial number of your Mac to see the specs.

It's always a good idea to read the return policy from the vendors, in case the RAM that you bought was not compatible with your computer.

Answer (score -3):

it should work.  i would just make sure you can return it just in case.  when you put the new ram in the mac will beep if the ram is not acceptable.

Comment: My Mac doesn't beep if the RAM is wrong, it sets a different pattern of lights on the mobo.